# How to patch Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: ubuntu, security, apache-2.4

I am running Apache 2.4.18 on an 16.04 server. Is this version patched through Ubuntu apt-get upgrade? I was ready about some security issues, but the upgrade command will not upgrade Apache.

```
rex:~$ apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-06-07T19:43:03
```

Do I need to apply patches, or will Ubuntu take core of it. If not, how can I upgrade to the latest 2.4 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check by `apt-get -s upgrade apache2` which will generate output similar to

```
apt-get -s upgrade  apache2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
=====> THE INFO YOU WANT IS HERE   <====== 
Calculating upgrade... Done
... other updates
```

Where the most relevant info is roughly one of the following:

- When you are already up to date that will show

  ```
  <package> is already the newest version
  ```
- When the package is not yet installed that will show

  ```
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
  <package> [+ dependancies]
  ```
- When the package has a uninstalled update available.

  ```
  The following packages will be upgraded:
  <package> [+ dependancies]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed the stock Apache version on Ubuntu 16.04, this will be patched with all relevant security fixes by Ubuntu until April 2021 and there is no need to manually upgrade to a newer upstream release of it.

Of course, you need to install the OS upgrades provided by Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you Sven. Looks like everything is up and patched.