# How do I make sure that all security updates applied to Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS with ESM support included?

Tags: apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04

Here's the partial answer to my question: [How to patch Apache 2.4.18 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?](https://serverfault.com/a/961269/) and here: [Will Ubuntu 16.04.6 updates ever include a version of Apache newer than 2.4.18?](https://serverfault.com/a/997869/)

My Apache version info:

```
apache2 -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2023-03-20T21:41:20
```

Here is the latest updates for Apache 2.4

```
2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17+esm10
```

I checked Ubuntu website at https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17/changelog and compare it with https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html

```
Fixed in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.42
low: mod_rewrite CWE-601 open redirect (CVE-2020-1927)
https://httpd.apache.org/security/vulnerabilities_24.html
```

and

```
apache2 (2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17) xenial-security; urgency=medium

  * SECURITY UPDATE: mod_rewrite redirect issue
    - debian/patches/CVE-2020-1927-1.patch: factor out default regex flags
      in include/ap_regex.h, server/core.c, server/util_pcre.c.
    - debian/patches/CVE-2020-1927-2.patch: add AP_REG_NO_DEFAULT to allow
      opt-out of pcre defaults in include/ap_regex.h,
      modules/filters/mod_substitute.c, server/util_pcre.c,
      server/util_regex.c.
    - CVE-2020-1927
  * SECURITY UPDATE: mod_proxy_ftp uninitialized memory issue
    - debian/patches/CVE-2020-1934.patch: trap bad FTP responses in
      modules/proxy/mod_proxy_ftp.c.
    - CVE-2020-1934
https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/a/apache2/apache2_2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17/changelog
```

It is not clear if other security issues up to CVE-2023-25690 fixed.
Can I trust Ubuntu that all security issues for Apache version 2.4.56 in the latest
*2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17+esm10* ? How do I check what is included in *esm10* updates?

Comment: Found this link about ESM change logs: [https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=xenial&details=apache](https://ubuntu.com/security/notices?order=newest&release=xenial&details=apache)

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 is EOL. Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: @djdomi The free version Ubuntu 16.04 is EOL, but the question is about the paid version 16.04 ESM which has an EOL date of 2026. https://ubuntu.com/security/esm

Comment: well if you pay for an EOL system then I suggest you to contact the vendor support about your inquiry

Comment: I use a free subscription of ESM.

Comment: So well, its **paid** version who has an EOL date of 2026. *Yours* already expired. Time to update.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt policy apache2
```

gives:

```
apache2:  
  Installed: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17+esm10  
  Candidate: 2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17+esm10
```

Comment: Yes. Your answer is included in my question `2.4.18-2ubuntu3.17+esm10`. How can we explain `esm10`?

Answer (score 0):

you could check for every CVE for example:
https://ubuntu.com/security/CVE-2023-25690

Comment: Beware, though.  CVEs might not be accurate for a vendor-supported distribution where the vendor backports fixes into versions of software specific to that distribution.  Or, in this case, where the vendor *used to* do that backporting but stopped as the specific free distribution is EOL.